# How to use Xpath on mule.payload which contains string arrray

Tags: mule

I have mule payload which contains 3 different soap request message.
How can I read the value of one of the xml tag/node present in 2nd soap request using MEL ?

e.g. message payload is as follows

```
[
<soap:Envelope>
    <book>
        <name>ABC</name>
        <author>ABCD</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>WXY</name>
        <author>WXYZ</author>
    </book>
<soap:Envelope> ,
<soap:Envelope>
    <fruit>
        <name>Apple</name>
        <color>Red</author>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <name>Orange</name>
        <color>Orange</author>
    </fruit>
<soap:Envelope> ,
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Envelope> 
]
```

I want to read the value of "name of all fruits" using xpath and MEL.

Answer (score 1):

If the payload is an array of String containing each element the XML, you can do this:

```
#[xpath('xpath expression', payload[1])]
```

Comment: I am getting error if I use above. I tried using <logger level="INFO" message=" Output : #[xpath('//fruit,message.payload[2]).text]  "/> 
but its also throwing the error. @Seba

Comment: You're not writing the xpath function properly. Check the format I put above. See that I am passing 2 arguments: the first is the xpath expression and the second the object on which the expression will be evaluated.

Comment: I am not good at xpath.   I am using following expression : <logger level="INFO" message=" Output : #[xpath('//fruit',message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)[3])]  "/> . I am getting org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@12bf1fe [Document: name null] . @Seba appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a copy and paste error in your example however

```
<color>Orange</author>
```

wont ever work

However assuming you mean the xml is something like:

```
<soap:Envelope>
<fruit>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <color>Red</color>
</fruit>
<fruit>
    <name>Orange</name>
    <color>Orange</color>
</fruit>
</soap:Envelope>
```

then you can use Mvel [xpath://fruit[1]/name/text()] to get indivdual xpath items 
or  [xpath://fruit/name/text()] to get all

A good site to test xpath queries are:
http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Comment: payload is array of String.